# unique values from a list

Tags: list, python-3.x, unique

How can I get 6 unique values from the list below?

```py
# List of donuts
Donuts = ['Apple Cinnamon',
         'Strawberry","Custard',
         'Sugar Ring',
         'Chocolate Caramel',
         'Lemon Circle',
         'Blueberry Blaster',
         'Strawberry Surprise',
         'Simple Sugar']
```

This is what I have so far:

```py
# Function - Random Selection of Donuts
def Generate_Random():
    if (len(Donuts)>0):
        choice.set(randint(0, len(Donuts)-1))
        stvRandomChoice.set (Donuts[choice.get()])
```

Comment: Wow! First question I see with all this bold &  big  text.....

Comment: Is it Ruby or Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this very easily with `random.sample(donuts, 6)`, which will return a list of 6 random elements from your list.

For more information see https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

**Edit:** Implemented for clarity:

```
import random

# List of donuts
Donuts = ['Apple Cinnamon',
          'Strawberry',
          'Custard',
          'Sugar Ring',
          'Chocolate Caramel',
          'Lemon Circle',
          'Blueberry Blaster',
          'Strawberry Surprise',
          'Simple Sugar']

# Function - Random Selection of Donuts
def Generate_Random(list, num):
    return random.sample(list, num)

# Print out randomly selected donuts using the above function
for element in Generate_Random(Donuts, 6):
    print element
```

Comment: ive tried this is didnt work ive tried the below can you advise where i would place your coding

Comment: #Function - Random Selection of Donuts

def Generate_Random():
    if (len(Dougnuts)>0):
       choice.set (randint(0, len(Dougnuts)-1))
       stvRandomChoice.set(Dougnuts[choice.get()])
       if (len(Dougnuts)>0):
              choice.set (randint(0, len(Dougnuts)-1))
              stvRandomChoice.set(Dougnuts[choice.get()])

Comment: I implemented my solution quickly to clarify. Please see the my edited answer. @ElisaSampson

Comment: Hi CoreyThe code works great, i am using 3.4 python but using this with tkinter to create an application.  Do you know how to run this as a button rather then use the 'print' command? sorry for being a pain

Comment: Sorry, I have never used tkinter. You may wish to create a new question with your updated code and the proper context and tags. I'm sure someone would be glad to help :).